# When installing Kali Linux, Windows 10 suddenly became unbootable

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

**Here's the story about the problem...**
Yesterday i was Kali Linux when the setup told me to reboot. I clicked OK on my Windows 10, when suddenly after restart, my dual booted Windows 7 booted up. Windows Boot Manager normally shows up, so i panic a bit. So I checked my files, and i was relieved to see they were there. Windows too, as the Linux setup says it could delete and replace files for the operating system. I haven't made a partition too, i'll tell you more later. So I thought to myself and said "Dangit, i can't do it, so I want to go back to Windows 10 and play games." Then i restarted the PC, and saw it automatically just loads to the Windows 7.

Now see, I don't mind Windows 7. In fact, i love it more than Windows 10. But if I choose to stay at Windows 7, i'm actually sacrificing my games. Windows 7 weirdly doesn't detect my NVIDIA GeForce 120, so I can't play any games or programs. Plus, my monitor runs on VGA GPU now, so monitor now updates so slow and so distorted I can't enjoy YouTube without this problem.

Then i read some articles, but i hate those types that says "dOwNlOaD tHiS sOfTwArE! iT cAn FiX yOuR pC!" because I want ways, not software. I tried one and it just wasted my time only to ask for premium. No, i don't wanna pay.

I checked the BIOS already, useless. Didn't detect it. All it detected was my Windows 7.

**If you don't wanna hear my story then here's the technical stuff.** I installed Kali Linux, and now my Windows 10 won't get detected. All my files are still there, even the Windows. Seems untouched. When i was installing Kali Linux, my dumb brain didn't make a partition, so i think it's about that or my OS is broken. BIOS and Boot Manager only detects my Windows 7 which is on the same disk as my Windows 10 but different partition. Now it only detects the full disk and it only brings me to my Windows 7. It shows up as a SATA device. I tried defaulting my BIOS, i tried booting it from Windows 7 (wasn't detected) and i even tried the softwares i despise. All of em detect a "problem" but needs money. I will call my relative (retired computer teacher but still insists on helping my technical problems) after the pandemic and ONLY as a last resort. I wish someone would help me...

Specs of my PC if you need it:

RAM : 2 GB

DISK SPACE : 465 GB

GPU : NVIDIA GeForce 120 (undetected by Windows 7)

CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10 Ghz

Disk : TOSHIBA DT01ACA050 ATA Device

P.S : Even if I sound like i know my tech stuff, I get nervous if it sounds like "One wrong step and you will lose your files.". So please try to make it simple? I'll do anything to have my Windows 10 back...

Comment: Windows Boot Manager has a specific way that it needs to be configured. Your best bet is to try and delete Kali Linux and then see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried __MSCONFIG__ from Windows 7 "Run". Open to __Boot__ and you should see which operating systems are available for you to boot. If you change to "; Default OS" make sure you check the box __Make all boot settings permanent__ _Not very good advice yet?_ Hope this helped you out.

Comment: Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is supposed to work. Questions should be questions; answers should be answers. [You can add your own *answer*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). There's no need to put "solved" in the title, just accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could have install kali in VMware. Running Kali on your Winodw might crash your system or make you loose files. You know Kali is quite flexible as an OS.

**My Recommendation**
I'd recommend, you remove the hardisk and format the system, as you said you don't wanna lost your gaming files and you are also a techy. Just backup the files first since it happened, you just have to try the formating option.

Comment: Do you think it will work? RAM is 2GB, i hope the install isn't too heavy